# Problem with compiling any HLSL effect

Tags: c#, xna, hlsl

My code is:

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream("ImageProcessing.fx", FileMode.Open,FileAccess.Read);
        CompiledEffect compiledEffect = Effect.CompileEffectFromFile(fs, null, null, CompilerOptions.None, TargetPlatform.Windows);
        fs.Close();
        effect = new Effect(graphics.GraphicsDevice, compiledEffect.GetEffectCode(), CompilerOptions.None, null);
```

and my fx file:

```
float4x4 xViewProjection;

struct VertexToPixel
{
float4 Position     : POSITION;
float4 Color        : COLOR0;
};

struct PixelToFrame
{
    float4 Color        : COLOR0;
};

    VertexToPixel SimplestVertexShader( float4 inPos : POSITION, float4 inColor : COLOR0)
{
    VertexToPixel Output = (VertexToPixel)0;

    Output.Position =mul(inPos, xViewProjection);

     Output.Color = inColor;

     return Output;
 }

 PixelToFrame OurFirstPixelShader(VertexToPixel PSIn)
 {
     PixelToFrame Output = (PixelToFrame)0;    

     Output.Color = PSIn.Color;    

     return Output;
 }

 technique Simplest
 {
     pass Pass
     {
         VertexShader = compile vs_2_0 SimplestVertexShader();
         PixelShader = compile ps_2_0 OurFirstPixelShader();
     }
 }
```

It so simple it shouldn't cause a problem yet there is such error:

```
ID3DXEffectCompiler: There were no techniques
ID3DXEffectCompiler: Compilation failed
```

Where is the error? 
There seems to be a problem with something else but i don't know where because other examples don't compile too.
Maybe some invalid char? But where? Or enter should be in unix format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the HLSL compiler has problems if the encoding on the file you're trying to compile is incorrect, and also if you're not using the right new line characters.  ex:

- http://blog.rthand.com/post/2008/11/12/DirectX-HLSL-compiler-chokes-on-unicode-sources.aspx
- http://www.gamedev.net/community/forums/topic.asp?topic_id=505884&whichpage=1&#3299434

Comment: Oh god it was the BOM on the start of file, Thanks very much!